# Java 8 migration analysis using SonarQube

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

I need to perform java8 migration analysis in my java code using [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/). The present rules do not cover changes related to streams,date time API, try with resources and some other rules which are mentioned [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/migrating-to-java-8.html) for java8 migration analysis using IntelliJ. Is there any way through which I can do Java8 migration analysis and find all instances where changes are required in my project.

Comment: There will hardly be any "required" changes in your code. In tens of thousands of lines of code I've seen migrated to Java 8 the only problem I found was that the traversal order of a HashMap had changed (a unit test erroneously relied on this order)

Comment: The problem is IntelliJ analysis shows me 380+ warnings for instances where java8 changes are required whereas using SonarQube i get only 21 code smells. So i don't think both are doing the same analysis for java8.

Comment: I don't think that those 380+ changes are "required", they are most probably "suggested". IntelliJ is very proactive at suggesting code improvements (or what it thinks are code improvements).

Comment: How can I add more rules in SonarQube that would find more instances where java8 migration changes are required in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a double handful of [rules tagged 'java8' on SonarQube.com](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#tags=java8), in addition to this [try-with-resouces rule](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2093) which had somehow escaped tagging until now.